# Mock testing a dependency-injected object

Tags: java, spring, testing, dependency-injection, mocking

I have four classes like below:

```
public class A(){

  public void getOne(){

    B objB = new B();
    String x = objB.getTwo();
  }
}



public class B(){

  public String getTwo(){

    C objC = new C();
    return objC.getThree();
  }
}


public class C(){

  D objD;

  public String getThree(){

    return objD.getFour();
  }
}

public class D(){

  public String getFour(){

    return "hi";
  }
}
```

In the above code, class `C` has `objD` which is being injected by Spring. When I try to test the `getOne()` method of class `A`, I get a null pointer exception because when the method call reaches class `C`, it has no `objD` instantiated (hence the exception). How can I test such methods where the sub-sub class has a method where that sub-sub class is dependency-injected by Spring?

Answer (score 1):

The test fails, and it's a good thing, because there's no way for Spring to inject dependencies inside an object it doesn't create by itself. If you're doing `new C()`, Spring doesn't know anything about it, and will never inject `objD` inside this C instance.

D should be injected in C, which should be injected in B, which should be injected in A. This way, you can test A by injecting a mock B; you can test B by injecting a mock C, and you can test C by injecting a mock D.

Answer (score 0):

While object `C` may be Spring injected, you are not realizing it in `B` (and therefore `A`) because you are using the `new` operator to instantiate `C`, which Spring won't intercept without some help from additional libraries (which I am assuming you are not using).

`new` is a dirty word when it comes to Inversion of Control, and I see it in both `A` and `B`.

Ideally, when you write a test for `A`, you do not want to depend on anything that it doesn't know about (in this case `C` and `D`).  You probably want to mock/stub an instance of `B` and have that injected into `A`.  I would recommend doing the same for `B` with regards to `C`.